# Please silently tag rocky-linux

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just created [rocky-linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/rocky-linux) and can see 16 questions searching [rocky linux](https://serverfault.com/search?q=rocky+linux+is%3Aquestion) with only one noise result dated 2018.

Given overall project support, I speculate this will increase, thus the tag.

Can someone please kindly silently add the tag to these questions?

Comment: I only asked because I thought there was some tool for doing this that was both silently and a little easier than manually editing each question. However, if it is just as easy for me to edit a couple each day, I can do that, no problem.

Answer (score 3):

The only silent-retag tooling available is by staff, not moderators. I've been reviewing the search and there are a number of questions that are already at the five tag limit. This is in part due to [fedora](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora), [centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/centos), and [redhat](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/redhat) being added to some questions. It isn't always clear which tag should be dropped to add the rocky one.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that.